# Why did NSDAP hate communism (socialism), despite having socialism within the party?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, german

Why did Germany during the era of NSDAP have a different point of view on socialism? It was not like the socialism that formed communism in the Soviet Union. I believe that Germany's fight against the Soviet Union was not only based on racial issues, but also on ideology ?

Comment: Why is the Democratic Peoples Republic of Korea not, well, democratic?

Comment: The context of my question is in the WWII era. I think the DPRK was created after the Soviet Union tried to spread communism in Korea during the Cold War era. Furthermore, it has a different meaning from Nazi socialism.

Comment: Sure, but words don’t always mean what you think they might, particularly (loaded) political terms. Nor are their meanings consistent across time and place.

Comment: I see. It now makes sense to me, after conducting a search on the various meanings of socialism, that this political and economic ideology can take many forms and has been implemented in different ways around the world, often in conjunction with other political and economic systems.

Comment: Perhaps socialism was window dressing to hide the nastiness from the electorate?

Comment: @JonCuster The *Democratic People's Republic of Korea* is a democratic (as defined by Lenin in 1902) state, since Article 5 of it's constitution states: *All state organs of the DPRK shall be organized and managed on the principle of [democratic centralism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_centralism).*

Comment: @MarkJohnson - and it closely adheres to the 'one man one vote' ethos, excepting only having one man... But, yes, words get used in many ways.

Comment: @JonCuster That too was common in socialist countries, since the party is always right any suggestion from the party must be right so voting ballets were placed directly into the ballet box  (and were considered valid without any marking).

Comment: Protecting this post - it has been flagged as potential troll bait, which is supported by the lack of documented preliminary research makes me suspicious. On the other hand, this is a new user, and two different reviewers have passed the question. If the question is not supported by additional research/formalism/rigor, I will close the question and allow the community to revise or delete.

Comment: @MCW Except that communism has been used in east asia as a vehicle for nationalism. North Korea is an ethno-state, China promotes its Han majority and is sinicizing Tibet. Vietnam used communism to unite the people against the colonial powers. The Khmer Rouge started out as communist nationalists too hence the red in the name.

Comment: @YusrilDewantara I think the main problem that many today associate the term Socialism **only** with that what Marx and Lenin wished to achive. But this was never the case. Even before 1920 there were many different versions most of which had compleatly different final goals.

Comment: This question is so opinion based! Who told you that NSDAP hated communism? They were allies when it was convenient and enemies when it was not. Normal game of big forces, that simple. Story about racial stuff is a fairy tale for children.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch Indeed, Germany and the Soviet Union were allies, but what I'm talking about is 'socialism,' which existed even before the Soviet Union was formed.

Answer (score 6):

> NSDAP have a different point of view on socialism?

It didn't really. The "socialism" in the party's name was never anything more than a great big steaming pile of marketing. They were always a far-right [Nationalist Populist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-wing_populism) party. The hallmark of [nationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalism) being a desire to have all of their own culture under the same state (and little to none of anybody else's), and the hallmark of [populism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populism) being an ideology that the common people are being controlled and thwarted by a nefarious elite.

Political science had not yet really fully studied populism, so it was not really a term in common use until the 1950's (although many similar right-wing parties did use "People's Party"). So [the original name of the party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazi_Party#Name) was just "The German Workers Party".

The "Workers" in there was a nod to the fact that in a democracy they needed *some* kind of appeal to to the working class in order to have any hope of getting a serious amount of votes. The only pro-worker program they really espoused was getting rid of the Jews and socialists and other assorted undesirables and traitors who were supposedly secretly controlling the government (again: this is what we today consider classic populism).

The "socialist" was inserted into the name in 1920, over Hitler's objections, and again purely as a marketing ploy. The party was positioned as a racist far-right anti-Marxist party both before and after the name change.

> In general, the manifesto was antisemitic, anti-capitalist,
> anti-democratic, anti-Marxist and anti-liberal. To increase its
> appeal to larger segments of the population, on the same day as
> Hitler's Hofbräuhaus speech on 24 February 1920, the DAP changed its
> name to the Nationalsozialistische Deutsche Arbeiterpartei ("National
> Socialist German Workers' Party", or Nazi Party). The word
> "Socialist" was added by the party's executive committee (at the
> suggestion of Rudolf Jung), over Hitler's initial objections, in
> order to help appeal to left-wing workers.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145708/discussion-on-answer-by-t-e-d-why-did-nsdap-hate-communism-socialism-despite); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

> Why did Germany during the era of NSDAP have a different point of view on socialism?

In short: it was the difference between:

> [Nationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalism) is an ideology that strives for identification and solidarity among all members of a nation and wants to unite the latter in a sovereign state.

and

> [Internationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalism_(politics)) refers to ideas or efforts that go beyond the framework of the nation state or that consider a transnational level to be decisive or worth striving for.

---

> [Nationalsozialismus – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalsozialismus#Bezeichnungen)
> **Bezeichnungen**
> „Nationaler Sozialismus“ bezeichnete im deutschsprachigen Raum seit etwa 1860 Verbindungen von nationalistischen und sozialistischen Ideen. Vom „Nationalsozialismus“ sprach zuerst die 1903 in Österreich gegründete Deutsche Arbeiterpartei, die sich 1918 in Deutsche Nationalsozialistische Arbeiterpartei (DNSAP) umbenannte. Entsprechend benannte sich auch die 1919 in Deutschland gegründete Deutsche Arbeiterpartei (DAP) 1920 in NSDAP um.
>
> Mit der Bezeichnung „Nationalsozialismus“ **grenzten** diese neuen Parteien ihre Ideologie **gegen den [Internationalismus](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalismus) der sozialdemokratischen und kommunistischen Parteien** und vom konservativen [Nationalismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalismus) älterer Parteien ab, indem sie sich deren Wählerschichten (Arbeitern und Mittelstand) als bessere Alternative anboten. Außerdem stellten sie einzelne antikapitalistische Forderungen in den Rahmen eines völkisch-rassistischen Nationalismus und präsentierten sich seit 1920 als „Bewegung“, nicht als Partei, um so Protestwähler und Politikverdrossene zu erreichen.
>
> > **Designations**
> > "National Socialism" has been used in German-speaking countries since around 1860 to describe the combination of nationalist and socialist ideas.  The German Workers' Party, which was founded in Austria in 1903 and renamed itself the German National Socialist Workers' Party (DNSAP) in 1918, first spoke of "National Socialism".  Accordingly, the German Workers' Party (DAP), founded in Germany in 1919, renamed itself NSDAP in 1920.
> >
> > With the term “National Socialism”, these new parties **differentiated their ideology from the [internationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalism_(politics)) of the social democratic and communist parties** and from the conservative [nationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalism) of older parties, offering their constituency (working class and middle class) a better alternative.  In addition, they placed individual anti-capitalist demands within the framework of a folkish-racist nationalism and presented themselves as a “movement” from 1920, not as a party, in order to reach protest voters and those disenchanted with politics.

---

**Sources**:

- [Nationalsozialismus – Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalsozialismus#Bezeichnungen) (in German)
- [Internationalism (politics) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalism_(politics))
- [Nationalism - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalism)

Answer (score -3):

This is a part of the very general pattern: your worst enemies are those whose views are close you your own, rather than those whose views differ radically. Examples:

For the early Christians, the worst animosity was
between various Christian sects (which differed very little) rather than between Christians and Pagans,

For the Catholic church the worst enemies were Muslims and Jews (fellow monotheists), protestants, heretics.

For Stalinists: Trotskyists and other "deviationists", rather than "capitalists".

For the Nazis: fellow socialists.

Comment: You dislike it but have nothing to comment?

Comment: Quite frankly, I'm surprised. There is nothing wrong with your answer. I don't understand the down voting either. You can add page 394 (or thereabouts) of Mein Kampf where Hitler word for word explains the difference between communism and national socialism: race. "take away the racial aspects, and you're left with communism".

Comment: No references - and any engagement with good sources would show that it is wrong. Start with Konrad Heiden.